# Let $\tau$ be lower limit topology on $\mathbb R.$ Then $(X,\tau)$ is not second countable.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\tau$ be lower limit topology on $\mathbb R.$ Then $(X,\tau)$ is
>   not second countable.

Suppose on the contrary there exists a countable basis for $(X,\tau)$. Let $\mathscr B=\{B_1,...,\}$ be the basis. Any non-empty open set is the union of elements of $\mathscr B.$ Where will I get a contradiction? How do I proceed the proof?

Comment: Isn't he proved that there exist an uncountable basis in the proof?

Comment: The first answer is fine.

Comment: How does in the proof guarentee there doesnot exist a countable basis?

Comment: The author proved that, given a basis $\mathcal B$, there is a one-to-one function from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathcal B$. Therefore, $\mathcal B$ has *at least* the cardinal of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Where will the proof fail,if we consider usual topology  on R?

Comment: For the usual topology, it is not true that, given a basis $\mathcal B$, for each $x\in\mathbb R$ there is a $B_x\in\mathcal B$ such that $\min B_x=x$. Actually, there is *no* open set $A$ such that $x\in O$ and that $\min A=x$.

Comment: I have still doubt on why minimum is taking?

Comment: Can't we take infimum for usual topology case ?

Comment: Sure we can. But there's reason why the function will be one-to one. And I shall answer no more questions here. If you have a new question, post it as such.